# How to implement Ruby max_by to return all elements which have the maximum value?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, monkeypatching, maxima

Ruby max_by method finds the maximal element form an array. Sometimes the maximal elements are with multipicity, in this case max_by chooses only one of them, seemingly arbitrarily. When I need all of them, I use this approach currently, to find the maximal values in an array of arrays:

```
sorted=ary.sort_by{|a,b| b}.reverse
max_score=sorted.first[1]
t=sorted.take_while{|z| z[1]==max_score}
```

But how could I monkey-patch the Array class with a "maxes_by" method, which accept a block, similarly to max_by, and returns an array of the maximal values?

Comment: There's no built-in for this, so you'll have to compose your own. You could introduce it as `Array#maxes_by` if you want, or even put it into `Enumerable`.

Comment: How does your input array look like?

Comment: I would like an implementation which works for every kind of arrays, nested arrays, etc. This is why one should pass a block. Anyway my array contains value pairs, as nested arrays, this can be seen from my example too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without writing a new, optimized method that returns the expected output, you can combine [`max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) and [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
maximum = array.max_by { |element| element[1] }
t = array.select { |element| element[1] == maximum[1] }
```

Another option might be to group all elements by the value in question (with [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)) and then just pick the list with the max value.

```
lists = array.group_by { |element| element[1] }
lists[lists.keys.maximum]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth a mention that the task could be done in a single pass through the array, or more generally, in a single pass through any collection whose class includes `Enumerable`.

```
module Enumerable
  def max_by_all
    return each unless block_given?
    last_yield = nil
    each_with_object([]) do |e,a|
      ye = yield(e)
      case last_yield.nil? ? -1 : last_yield <=> ye
      when -1
        a.replace([e])
        last_yield = ye
      when 0
        a << e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
arr = [2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 1]
arr.max_by_all(&:itself)
  #=> [5, 5]
```

```
arr =  ["style", "assets", "misty", "assist", "corgi", "bossy", "bosses", "chess"]
arr.max_by_all { |s| s.count('s') }
  #=> ["assets", "assist", "bosses"]
```

```
h = { a: 1, b: 3, c: 2, d: 3, e: 1 }
h.max_by_all(&:last)
  #=> [[:b, 3], [:d, 3]]
```

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.max_by_all.map { |n| 2*n }
  #=> [2, 4, 6]
```

In the last example `max_by_all` has no block and therefore returns an enumerator which merely enumerates the elements of `self`. This behaviour may seem pointless but I've provided for it (the line `return each unless block_given?`) to mimic the behaviour of [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) when no block is provided.

Comment: And how can I monkey patch the Array class with this?

Comment: @Konstantin You can check a solution Monkey Patching the Array class right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336503/7644846 . But you can use the ruby refinements to monkey patch without possible damages to your system.

Comment: Konstantin, I revised my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Monkey-Patch

```rb
class Array
  def maxes_by
    maximal = max_by { |x| yield(x) }
    select { |x| yield(x) == yield(maximal) }
  end
end
```

- Usage

```rb
> ['house', 'car', 'mouse'].maxes_by { |x| x.length }

=> ['house', 'mouse']
```

But I don't recommend to monkey patch the `Array` class, this practice is dangerous and can potentially lead to undesirable effects on your system.

For our good, ruby language provides a nice feature to overcome this problem, the [Refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), which is a safe way for monkey patching on ruby.

To simplify, with the [Refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) you can monkey patch the `Array` class and the changes will only be available inside the scope of the class that is using the refinement! :)

You can use the refinement inside the class you are working on and you are ready to go.

#### Using Refinements

```rb
module MaxesByRefinement
  refine Array do
    def maxes_by
      maximal = max_by { |x| yield(x) }
      select { |x| yield(x) == yield(maximal) }
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  using MaxesByRefinement

  def test
    a = %w(house car mouse)
    a.maxes_by { |x| x.length } # maxes_by is available here!
  end
end
```

- Usage

```rb
> MyClass.new.test

=> ['house', 'mouse']
```